# sql Agent job failure: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm executing a SSIS package in a SQL agent job configuring it to run in 32 bit mode. I've even tried giving fully qualified name like this `D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe`, but still the job fails with the following error.

> Message
>   The process could not be created for step 1 of job (reason: %1 is not a valid Win32 application).  The step failed.

Please help.

Comment: This seems on the first sight as a buggy error message. %1 normally should be replaced using the win32 application name. Did you use "" around your path?

Comment: Try the solution from msdn forum. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/02797f5d-03e4-42a0-bc40-b42d5aad5aed/1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-ssis-job-error-?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: yes i did tried "" as well @Ionic

Comment: I checked the link @Tjasun . I did not find any duplicate file or file with 0 KB size